# Getting an instruction profile using Valgrind

Tags: profiling, valgrind, instrumentation

Is it possible to use valgrind to get information on the instruction profile of a program run. By instruction profile I mean number of instructions broken down to instruction of each type. E.g: 'n1' MOV, 'n2' CALL etc. If not what other tools exist which can do it?

Answer (score 3):

I think, there is no ready tool for this task with valgrind. You may try to write some scripts to get such information, or get basic data by hand with GUI.

There is `callgrind` tool in valgrind to profile program executions:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind [callgrind-options] ./your-program
```

(Check http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html)

With it you can get profile with exact data of each instruction execution count (`Ir` event) and total number of executed instructions, but there will be no aggregated info on n1 MOVs, n2 CALLs, etc.

With `--dump-instr=yes` callgrind option there will be exact data of execution count of every machine instruction; this data can be viewed with `kcachegrind` GUI in "Assembler" tab. Not sure if `callgrind_annotate` will parse such file and show the annotated disassembly, but it is possible to parse `callgrind.out.$pid` output of callgrind by some perl/python script (this file is text-based - http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-format.html - there will be hex addresses and offsets according to "3.1.6. Subposition Compression"). You will get addresses of machine instructions and execution counts for every address, so script may combine counts with disassembly.

(Other way is to switch to some inexact profiler like `perf` or `oprofile` to get the same annotated disassembly as text and parse it by custom script. Result will be not exact as with valgrind, but it is easier to get counts with commands in text form)

PS: I think that writing script is easier than hacking valgrind's plugin (`callgrind`) with adding several counters for every instruction type. This is still possible, but is much harder and will slow down the instrumented program several times more than plain callgrind.